# AngularJS Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this issue has been mentioned several times before, but I couldn't seem to make any of those solutions work for me.

In my controller I have a function which is meant to be called from within an ng-repeat loop. The ng-repeat iterates through a list of servers and this function is called through a method on the view to get some environment data about that server.

This function seems to be the root of the problem but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Function in controller:

```
function getServHead(data) {
    SearchFactory.servHeader(data).then(
        function (response) {
            $log.info(response);
            vm.searchData.server.sh = response;
            return vm.searchData.server.sh;
        },
        function (error) {
            $log.error('Error getting server header data', error);
            vm.getTeamHeadInfoError = 'Error retrieving server header data';
        })
}
```

Here's an example of the data I get back:

```
{
  "name": "dcsql01",
  "isVirtual": false,
  "os": "Windows",
  "isInDMZ": false
}
```

How I'm calling from the view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="server in vm.searchData.server">
  <td>
    <a href="/server/{{server.Name}}">
    {{vm.getServHead(server.AssetID)}}
    <span ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.isVirtual == true" class="fa fa-cloud fa-lg"> </span>
    <span  ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.isVirtual != true"class="fa fa-tasks fa-lg"> </span>
    <span ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.isInDMZ == true" class="fa fa-user-secret fa-lg"> </span>
    <span ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.isInDMZ != true" class="fa fa-university fa-lg"> </span>
    <span ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.os == 'windows' || 'Windows'" class="fa fa-windows fa-lg"> </span>
    <span ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.os == 'linux' || 'Linux'" class="fa fa-linux fa-lg"> </span>
    {{server.Name}}</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <td> <span class='health'>100</span> </td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried returning the GET response like the Angular help page for this error suggested and have tried various other SO answers to this question but am still running into the same problem.

If anyone is able to give some insight into what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Server list call in controller:

```
function getServers() {
    SearchFactory.getServer(searchID).then(
        function (response) {
            $log.info(response);
            vm.searchData.server = response;
        },
        function (error) {
            $log.error('Error getting server search data', error);
            vm.getServerInfoError = 'Error retrieving server search data';
        })
}
```

This is run on initialization and passes what's in the params (searchID) to the API which returns a basic array of server objects.

Comment: Really bad idea initializing ajax requests from view function. First that function doesn't return anything and also it will be called at least twice per digest cycle per repeated element. Should be done in conjunction with other data request in service

Comment: Confusing what objective is since each request of `getServHead()` overwrites whole `vm.searchData.server.sh` object

Comment: So the function does return the requested data, but then it goes into the infinite loop. I was figuring the returned object would just overwrite each call and be fine, but obviously that's not the case. What would be a better way?

Comment: Not at all clear what relationships are between `server` objects and what `vm.searchData.server.sh` is. Would be a lot simpler if `vm.searchData.server.sh` was a property os `server`

Comment: Basically, the API I'm pulling from has an endpoint for getting a list of servers which I'm calling through my controller on initialization and dumps it into vm.searchData.server. Then from within the ng-repeat it makes an API call to get the environment data which is dumped into vm.searchData.server.sh

Comment: can you not make the individual requests be nested property of server objects? Then in controller update each `server` with response? Otherwise you need to change `vm.searchData.server.sh` to array or object and match the indexing instead of overwriting it each iteration

Comment: Could you expand on or point me in the direction of how I could go about this? I'm still a bit new to Angular and JS in general, so I'm not entirely sure how to do what you're requesting.

Comment: Show code to get server data

Comment: server data call added.

Comment: Add `track by $index` to your `ng-repeat`. Overall, and please don't take it personally, it's a very bad design: ont only you trigger AJAX requests as part of view expression, but also you adjust the external collection when processing the response.

Comment: Where does `searchId` come from? It's not passed into `getServers()` and the data is in `response.data` ... it's not `response`

Comment: var searchID = $stateParams.id;

Answer (score 0):

For starters the actual data in `then(response)` is contained in `response.data`.

the following will populate the head data in a property `server.sh` for ech server in the repeat

```
function getServers() {
  return SearchFactory.getServer(searchID).then(function(response) {
      $log.info(response.data);
      vm.searchData.server = response.data;
      return vm.searchData.server;
    },
    function(error) {
      $log.error('Error getting server search data', error);
      vm.getServerInfoError = 'Error retrieving server search data';
    })


}


getServers().then(function(servers) {

  servers.forEach(function(server) {
    var id = server.AssetID;
    SearchFactory.servHeader(id).then(function(response) {
        $log.info(response);
        server.sh = response.data;

      },
      function(error) {
        $log.error('Error getting server header data', error);
        vm.getTeamHeadInfoError = 'Error retrieving server header data';
      });

  });

});
```

If you want all the dat retrieved before passing it to the view you will need to create array of promises and use `$q.all()`

Example view change would be:

Change

```
<span ng-if="vm.searchData.server.sh.isVirtual == true" class="fa fa-cloud fa-lg"> </span>
```

To

```
<span ng-if="server.sh.isVirtual == true" class="fa fa-cloud fa-lg"> </span>
```